# Doctrine get data across more table relationships

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

How can I handle this situation.

I have tables: `Item, Item_Picture, Vendor`

`Item_Picture` has relation to `Item (item_id)`

`Item` has relation to `Vendor (vendor_id)`

What are the ways how to get `Vendor` from `Item_Picture`?

I know how to `getItem` from `Item_Picture`.
But can I `getVendor` somehow from `Item_Picture` too?

For example, I can get what I want from Controller like this:

```
$pictureRepository = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
                          ->getRepository(ItemPicture::class);
$picture = $pictureRepository->find(1);
$vendor = $picture->getItem()->getVendor();
```

I am interested in more clean ways perhaps?

Comment: Read here please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the way query builder helps to build queries like this because it is closer to real sql query and avoid load all the repository.

```
$qb = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(['c.venderName']);
$qb->from(ItemPicture::class, 'a');
$qb->leftJoin('a.item', 'b');
$qb->leftJoin('b.vendor', 'c');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('a.id', ':id'));
$qb->setParameter('id', 1);
$vendor = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```